# Joomla 4 Controller naming convention and toolbar button tasks

Tags: joomla-4

I started a component com_xxx_yyy in Joomla 4 from scratch to learn the new API the hard way.

Parts of the structure

```
- Controller
--- DisplayController.php
--- YyyController.php
- View
--- Yyy
------ HtmlView.php
--- Yyys
------ HtmlView.php
```

In Yyys/HtmlView.php I add a toolbar button `$toolbar->addNew('yyy.new')`
then Joomla 4 uses the `YyyController.php` but uses the component name `option=com_yyy`

If I change the button to `$toolbar->addNew('xxx_yyy.new')` then it uses the right component name `option=com_xxx_yyy` but wants the Controller be called `Xxx_YyyController.php`

The most examples I found where the trivial default way. I looked into Joomla! Docu and the boilerplate on github.

In Joomla! 3 you could to such naming mappings in the xxx_xxx.php or the controller.php, but both not existing in Joomla! 4.

I looked into com_content and there it is exactly how I want.
view articles adds a button article.new and then it loads option=com_content;view=article

But I don't see the missing point on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the reason myself.

Joomla 4 uses the namespace to detect the components name and creates the `option=com_xxx_yyy` from it.

So a namespace like

`Vendor/Component/XXX_YYY` results in `option=com_xxx_yyy`

`Vendor/Component/XZYZZZ` results in `option=com_xzyzzz`